# C# - Multiple producer threads with single consumer thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, blocking, producer-consumer

Working on a C# project at the minute - a general idea of what I'm trying to do is...

A user has one or more portfolios with symbols they are interested in,
Each portfolio downloads data on the symbols to csv, parses it, then runs a set of rules on the data,
Alerts are generated based on the outcomes of these rules
The portfolios should download the data etc. whenever a set interval has passed

I was planning on having each portfolio running on it's own thread, that way when the interval has elapsed, each portfolio can proceed to download the data, parse and run the rules on it concurrently, rather  than one by one. The alerts should then be pushed onto another thread (!) that contains a queue of alerts. As it receives alerts, it sends them off to a client.

A bit much but what would be the best way to go about this with C# - using threads, or something like background worker and just having the alert-queue running on a separate thread?

Any advice is much appreciated, new to some of this stuff so feel free to tell me if I'm completely wrong :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [blocking collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997371.aspx). This is new in c# 4.0 to support producer consumer scenario.

It also supports 1 consumer and multiple producer.

Comment: Yeah I was looking at that, or ConcurrentQueue to hold the alert messages - I'm guessing this would run on a new thread, and each portfolio would run on it's own thread as well and just contain a pointer to the queue?

Comment: Probably more OO-ish to have a 'SendAlerts' class with an abstract method that takes the alert as parameter.  You can then subclass it to implement the BlockingCollection and thread as private members.  This nicely encapsulates the alerting of clients and allows you to easily change it later, should it become necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If this is entirely interval driven and you can upload alerts to the client at the end of each interval, then you can use a simplified approach:

When your interval timer fires:

1. Use TPL to launch simultaneous tasks to parse data, giving each task a callback method to pass alerts back to main.
2. The callback writes alerts to a List protected by a lock statement.
3. Wait for all tasks to complete. Then execute a continuation routine to forward the alerts to the client.
4. Restart the interval timer.

If you need to start processing the next interval before the upload is finished, you can use a double-buffered approach where you write to one List, give that to the upload method, and then start writing alerts to a new List, switching back and forth between lists as you collect and upload alerts.